# Test history is not available in Allure report

Tags: pytest, allure

I am using Allure framework to generate report for the tests written in pytest.
In the allure generated report, it generates the trends graphs such as duration trend, categories trend, retries trend successfully. However, when I check the 'History' of each test, it does not show the result of past runs.

This is how I generate the report:

1. Download allure report of the previous run
2. Run the test and store the result.

```
pytest tests --alluredir=allure-result
```

3. Copy the history of previous allure report to the new report directory

```
cp -r allure-previous-report/history allure-result/history
```

4. Generate allure report

```
 allure generate allure-result --clean -o allure-report
```

5. Open the allure report:

```
allure open allure-report -h localhost -p 8083
```

I expected to see the historical results of the tests but for some reason `History` tab is empty for all the testcase and cannot really understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm confusing that the name of `alluredir` in the second step is the same as the name of the dir where you store the HTML-report.

Comment: @VladimirYakovenko The name of the alluredir in second step is `allure-result` and the newly generated HTML report is stored in `allure-report` directory, so they are two different directories.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying a previously run report files into the most recently run test report, and then generating.

The documentation says that you must take the previously run report files and copy them into a history/ directory with your most recently run **results** directory.

NOTE: I believe that copying the files with --perserve=timestamps is required

Here is an example of how to do it, assuming that your project is configured to use allure-results and allure-report directories:

```
Make sure you have the previous report generated in the allure-report directory. (with cp --perserve=timestamps)

Remove the allure-results directory.

Run the tests.

Copy the allure-report/history subdirectory to allure-results/history.

Generate the new report.
```

https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-history/

Comment: Yes, I am doing like you suggested by copying history sub-directory from previous report  to newly run test results  (Step 3) and generating the new allure report but it is not showing the history of the test in the report.

Comment: I also had issues here. copying the allure-report/history files to the allure-results/history using the --perserve=timestamps flag made it work for me.

Ill update my answer

Comment: You can also add the directory containing the report history (i.e. allure-report) to the 'allure generate' command via:

'allure-generate path/to/results path/to/allure-report -o output'